# nodejs pause sax stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, stream, sax

I am parsing super large XML files using [sax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax%22sax%22).
I am creating a readStream from my XML file and piping it into sax like this:

```
this.sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
this.sourceStream
    .pipe(this.saxStream);
```

I am listening to some events like this:

```
this.saxStream.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error(`Error during XML Parsing`, err);
});
this.saxStream.on("opentag", (node) => {
    // doing some stuff
});
this.saxStream.on("text", (t) => {
    // doing some stuff
});
this.saxStream.on("closetag", () => {
    if( this.current_element.parent === null ) {
        this.sourceStream.pause();
        this.process_company_information(this.current_company, (err) => {
            if( err ) {
                logger.error("An error appeared while parsing company", err);
            }
            this.sourceStream.resume();
        });
    }
    else {
        this.current_element = this.current_element.parent;
    }
});
this.saxStream.on("end", () => {
    logger.info("Finished reading through stream");
});
```

After a specific end tag comes into the sax stream the stream needs to pause, current elements need to be processed and then the stream can continue.
As you can see in my code I tried to pause the `sourceStream` however I found out that pausing a readStream won't work if it is piped.

So my general question is **how can I make the sax parser pause until currently parsed elements are processed?**

I`ve read about unpiping and pausing and then piping again and resuming, is this really the way to do this, also it is reliable?

To illustrate better here are some logs:

```
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: New root tag found
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
```

What I actually want would be a log like this:

```
debug: New root tag found
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: New root tag found
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: New root tag found
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: New root tag found
debug: Done with root tag, can continue stream
debug: New root tag found
```

In it's current state sax is much faster then the processor, not pausing the stream will therefore lead to memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

`sax` is not actively maintained at the moment (https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/issues/238). And I would recommend you to migrate to another parser. For example to `saxes` https://github.com/lddubeau/saxes.

Instead of pausing/resuming the stream you may use a `for-await-of` construct with a `Generator` and an `Iterable` (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_consuming_readable_streams_with_async_iterators).

Install deps:
`yarn add emittery saxes` or `npm install emittery saxes`

And then do something like this:

```js
import {createReadStream} from 'fs';
import {SaxesParser, SaxesTagPlain} from 'saxes';
import Emittery from 'emittery';

export interface SaxesEvent {
  type: 'opentag' | 'text' | 'closetag' | 'end';
  tag?: SaxesTagPlain;
  text?: string;
}

/**
  * Generator method.
  * Parses one chunk of the iterable input (Readable stream in the string data reading mode).
  * @see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data
  * @param iterable Iterable or Readable stream in the string data reading mode.
  * @returns Array of SaxesParser events
  * @throws Error if a SaxesParser error event was emitted.
  */
async function *parseChunk(iterable: Iterable<string> | Readable): AsyncGenerator<SaxesEvent[], void, undefined> {
  const saxesParser = new SaxesParser<{}>();
  let error;
  saxesParser.on('error', _error => {
    error = _error;
  });

  // As a performance optimization, we gather all events instead of passing
  // them one by one, which would cause each event to go through the event queue
  let events: SaxesEvent[] = [];
  saxesParser.on('opentag', tag => {
    events.push({
      type: 'opentag',
      tag
    });
  });

  saxesParser.on('text', text => {
    events.push({
      type: 'text',
      text
    });
  });

  saxesParser.on('closetag', tag => {
    events.push({
      type: 'closetag',
      tag
    });
  });

  for await (const chunk of iterable) {
    saxesParser.write(chunk as string);
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    yield events;
    events = [];
  }

  yield [{
    type: 'end'
  }];
}

const eventEmitter = new Emittery();
eventEmitter.on('text', async (text) => {
  console.log('Start');
  await new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve1) => {
      console.log('First Level Promise End');
      resolve1();
    });
    console.log('Second Level Promise End');
    resolve();
  });
});

const readable = createReadStream('./some-file.xml');
// Enable string reading mode
readable.setEncoding('utf8');
// Read stream chunks
for await (const saxesEvents of parseChunk(iterable) ?? []) {
  // Process batch of events
  for (const saxesEvent of saxesEvents ?? []) {
    // Emit ordered events and process them in the event handlers strictly one-by-one
    // See https://github.com/sindresorhus/emittery#emitserialeventname-data
    await eventEmitter.emitSerial(event.type, event.tag || event.text);
  }
}
```

Also have a look at the main discussion of this solution https://github.com/lddubeau/saxes/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue in the future, here is what else I tried how I finally made it work, even though it's somewhat of a workaround.

I tried to pipe a pause stream in between trying [pause-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pause%20stream) and [pass-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pass-stream) as those are supposed to buffer when beeing paused. For some reason this again didn't change the behavior at all.

Finally I decided to attack the problem by it's roots, instead of creating a ReadingStream and piping it into sax, I am using [line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) to read lines from the XML bulk and writing into sax parser. This line reading process now can be paused correctly and finally helped me achieve the desired behavior

Comment: What if your source XML is a single line?